# Running parallel uploads with multiple users using jmeter

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, sftp, jsch

I have a jmx script which makes jsch connection and upload files in parallel using ultimate thread group with one user with below configuration and provide output as well

### Ultimate Thread Group

Start Thread count - 5
Start up delay - 600 secs
Hold load for - 1800 secs

### JSR223 Sampler

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

class Monitor implements SftpProgressMonitor{
//Progress monitoring code
}

def jsch = new Jsch()
def session = jsch.getSession("xyz", "xyz", "xyz")
session.setPassword("abc")
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
channelSftp.cd("xyz");
def f1 = new File("Test.txt");
channelSftp.put(new java.io.FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName()+Math.random(), new Monitor(SampleResult));
session.disconnect();
```

Now is there any way to do the same thing with multiple different users taking some thread out of ultimate start thread count instead for only 1 user taking all threads like running 5 different users concurrently taking 2 threads out of 10 start threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for parameterization, if you create a CSV file named `users.csv` looking like:

```
username
xyz
xyz1
xyz2
etc.
```

and add it to your JSR223 Sampler like this:

[image]

once you change this line:

```
def session = jsch.getSession("xyz", "xyz", "xyz")
```

to this one:

```
def session = jsch.getSession(vars.get("username"), "xyz", "xyz")
```

each JMeter thread (virtual user) on each iteration will take the next line from the CSV file and send the new username.

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

Also there is [jmeter-ssh-sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler)  plugin which adds SSH and SFTP protocols support to JMeter so you won't have to write the code and will be able to use GUI

Comment: I have one more doubt, As per my configuration of Ultimate Thread group, i am running with 5 parallel threads right that means 5 connection will be open in the entire test suite for 30 mins? Is this understanding correct? 
If yes, then me adding 5 diff users in the csv, means that each user will have only 1 session and suppose if i increase the thread to 10 and keep 5 users in csv, then will it start taking 1st user again in 6th thread?

Comment: It's a separate question which is not related to original and showing you don't understand what your code is doing. In any way comments section is not sufficient for answering the question comprehensively so I would recommend checking it yourself by using [${__threadNum}](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) functions combination along with [Debug PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor)

Comment: Maybe i was not able to explain it right, it is actually related to question itself. Let me rephrase and edit the question

Comment: The question in its current form has been answered, I'm not following any edits

Comment: I think i figured it out using CSV Data set config. So basically if you add 4 users name and give 10 threads then all 4 users will keep on working iteratively in each thread and the number of times each user will work is depending on the current thread to finish. That means overall one user can hit as many times depending on the hold load time we have kept.
Thank you for the help.